# CMake: the source does not match the source used to generate cache

Tags: cmake

Error

```
CMake Error: The source "C:/Users/Luberski/Repos/rpggame/CMakeLists.txt" does not match the source "C:/Users/Luberski/Repos/PokeTrade/CMakeLists.txt" used to generate cache.  Re-run cmake with a different source directory.
```

File structure

```
rpggame
├── include
│   └── include_files.hpp
├── src
│   └── source_files.cpp
├── .gitignore
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── main.cpp
```

Command that evokes this error but was working fine for previous project

```
cmake -S . -B /build
```

I deleted build directory multiple times, made sure there was no CMakeCache file in the project, deleted every other projects on my drive but still it's not working.

Comment: "I deleted build directory multiple times" - Have you actually deleted `/build` directory, which is the **top-level** directory in the whole **filesystem** (not in the project directory)?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I deleted rpggame/build and tried to remake the whole thing but it does not work

Comment: Once again, you specify `/build` which is an **absolute path**. It is NOT `rpggame/build`.

Comment: oh god, you're right